# Redirect to the same after form submission with error messages in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

This is my login page http://localhost:3000. After form submission I want the page should redirect to the same page if any error occurs and finally want to show those messages in the login page.Currently i am able to the show messages in the login page.But the problem is that the url becomes http://localhost:3000/login as the page redirecting to this url after form submit. I want, it should be localhost:3000.

So is it possible in express.js. I have seen that redirect method does not carry any extra params as error or something like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Other people will have no way of visiting your page if you are using the `localhost` as an address to share it.

Comment: yes it's true. But is that possible to redirect to the same page ignoring localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Simply redirect the request from login to '/' as:

```
app.get('/login',function(req,res){
 //login validation and error messages
 res.redirect('/');
});
```

To display the error messages back to the login page, you have to store the error messages in session, as res.redirect will end the request-response cycle and messages in request will be removed. So, either you manually store in session and set it in res.locals to get the message directly on the login view or you use `req-flash` [module](https://github.com/maximilianschmitt/req-flash) to display flash messages.

Comment: Thanks nivesh for your valuable response. I will definitely try and let you know

Comment: was it helpful, if yes then plz upvote the solution.

Comment: I am looking for a code to prevent page redirect after form submission. for example the submitting route is ```router.post('/submit')``` but wish for page to remain at ```/form``` after submitting.